# problems passing a php variable into JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass a php variable into JavaScript. I have to get from a  database the questions(randomly, one by one) and if the end user responses correctly,
the program is doing something else.

database

```
+------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------+
| q_id | description           | text          | answer          |
+------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------+
|    1 |What is the capital    | United States | Washington D.C. |
|    2 |What is the capital    | California    | Sacramento      |
|    3 |What is the capital    | Maryland      | Annapolis       |
+------+-----------------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

In the php file, variables `$question` and `$correctAnswer` have the following values:

php code:

```php
$sql="SELECT description, text, answer  FROM Questions";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $question=$row['description']."of ".$row['text']."?";
   echo($question);
   $correctAnswer=$row['answer'];
   //echo($correctAnswer);
}
```

javascript code:

```js
var rightAnswer;
function takeQuestion()
{
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
           document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           rightAnswer ='<?php echo $correctAnswer;?>';
           alert(rightAnswer); 
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getQuestion.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

The program is printing randomly the questions, but I have problems passing the variable
`$correctAnswer` to Javascript. Variable `rightAnswer` in JavasScript should take the value
of php variable `$correctAnswer`. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to send answer along with question from getQuestion.php

Comment: what js error you are getting

Comment: in the alert box I have: <?php echo $correctAnswer;?>; if I do not use quotes, the error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP inside while loop do this

```
$question=$row['description']."of ".$row['text']."?|".$row['answer'];
echo($question);
```

in your java script

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var elements = xmlhttp.responseText.split("|");
       document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=elements[0];
       var rightAnswer = elements[1];
       alert(rightAnswer); 
    }
```

This is an idea. Change it to way that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change Your javascript as:

Call it as responseXml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rightAnswer;
function takeQuestion()
{
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
           xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
           document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('question')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
           rightAnswer =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('answer')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
           alert(rightAnswer); 
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getQuestion.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 }

 </script>
```

Change Your php file as:

```
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 header ('Cache-Control: no-cache');
 header ('Cache-Control: no-store' , false);     // false => this header not override the previous similar header

$sql="SELECT description, text, answer  FROM Questions";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   $question=$row['description']."of ".$row['text']."?";
   //echo($question);
   $correctAnswer=$row['answer'];
   //echo($correctAnswer);
} 


$xmlStr='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <question>'.$question.'</question>
   <answer>'.$correctAnswer.'</answer>
</data>
';
echo $xmlStr;
?>
```

Comment: I have the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null, in this line: document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('question')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

Comment: How can I fix the problem? I like the idea of  using XML, but I am pretty new using it.

Comment: I know, but why I have that error? I upvoted your answer. It seems to be very elegant, but I really want to make it to work :)

Comment: Please now check the updated code for php file.do not forget to put connection in your php file.also there should be no extra space in it.

Comment: in JavaScript I only added the code for if() condition, and in php file I added 3 'header' lines and $xmlStr=... and echo $xmlStr. I also added mysql_close($con); before I closed php tag. Can I place header lines wherever in php code, or should be the first 3 lines of my php code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19404/discussion-between-vikas-umrao-and-lavinia)

Answer (score 0):

when you have Javascript and PHP on the same page, then you can pass data to the javascript using json_encode:

```
<?php
$var = 'hello';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var v = <?= json_encode($var); ?>;
</script>
```

without quotes

if you make an ajax call - the variable is not passed through the PHP, but as an http request. You use plain JS in that case

Comment: in your case - there's no php with the javascript. only plain JS